# Need to extract the text in first occurrence of pattern

Tags: awk, grep

I have one file where it consists of several lines like below:

```
 part1 { CORE_LK0 }  -group { LK0_GROUP } -module { 20rx }
 Ignore no3  { CORE_ft0 } -sync { n7 }
```

I need to extract the text in first occurrence of {}. 
I tried this :

```
grep "{.*}" file.txt
```

My output:

```
part1 { CORE_LK0 }  -group { LK0_GROUP } -module { 20rx }
Ignore no3  { CORE_ft0 } -sync { n7 }
```

But desired output is need to grep only the first occurrence of {}:

```
CORE_LK0
CORE_ft0
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Try `sed -n 's/^[^{}]*{\([^{}]*\)}.*/\1/p' file.txt`

Comment: Thaks @Wiktor Stribizew. Its working. But I didn't understood the above command properly.

Comment: I have explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed` for this:

```
sed -n 's/^[^{}]*{ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *}.*/\1/p' file > results
```

Or, if there can be any chars but `{` and `}` in between the first set of curly braces,

```
sed -n 's/^[^{}]*{ *\([^{}]*\) *}.*/\1/p' file > results
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/H3utfh).

**Details**

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output (unmatched lines won't get printed)
- `s/` - substitution command
- `^[^{}]*{ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *}.*` - match

  - `^` - start of string
  - `[^{}]*` - 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
  - `{ *` - `{` and 0 or more spaces
  - `\([[:alnum:]_]*\)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more letters, digits or `_`
  - `*}` - 0 or more spaces and `}`
  - `.*`  - the rest of the line
- `\1` - replace with the whole line with the contents of Group 1
- `p` - prints the value that was in Group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/{ [^}]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/{ [^}]*/){                      ##Using match function to match from { to till first occurence of }
  print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)     ##printing sub-string of current line from RSTART+2 to til RLENGTH-2
}
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Just for fun, recommended is above solution only(written in GNU `grep` and tested with shown samples only).

```
rev Input_file | grep -oP '.*} \K.*' | rev | grep -oP '.* { \K.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Perl:

```
$ perl -lnE 'say $1 if /^[^{]*\{([^}]*)\}/' file
 CORE_LK0 
 CORE_ft0
```

Regex explanation:

```
/^[^{]*\{([^}]*)\}/


 ^                    start of line anchor
  ^  ^                character class
   ^                  negated -- any character OTHER THAN {
      ^               * is 0 or more of that character class
       ^              \{ is a literal {
         ^    ^       (    ) capture group to define $1 
           ^ ^        0 or more characters OTHER THAN }
                 ^    literal }
```